# call a widget class from its name as a string in flutter

Tags: string, firebase, flutter, widget

I am using tab bar view in flutter, and I want each tab to map to specific screen (class widget). So, I am thinking of making a fire base collection named tabs, and creating documents in this collection for every screen. and each document has two main string fields: 1-name (to be used to write on the tab itself). the second one is screen: and it has the name of the class widget I want to map to this tab name. The problem is I can't store the type of filed in fire base as widget, so how can I call the widget class from the string type which holds its name?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything like `eval`. Dart uses a tree shaker. If it thinks the class is unused then the class will not be part of the final binary app. You'd have to use a big `switch` from string to calling the class constructor. That way the compiler can see the class is used.